# Highlighting a QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt4, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget full of rectangular icons of different color, which serves as a color selection dialog for our app. I do not like the highlight on them, since it is not aligned properly, as evident from the picture attached.

[image]

How do I fix this? Any ideas in general for better highlights would also be great!

Thanks,
Sayan

Answer (score 0):

you need to sub-classing `QItemDelegate` and reimplement its `paint` method, then using `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate` install it on your `QListWidget`.